# Update a row in database while retaining the previous data in other columns if their input is blank

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form where the user can update a student by entering the username of the student. But if the user only wants to update the firstname and leaves the lastname blank, this will remove the last name from the mysql database.

html form:

```
<form class="" action="updateStudent.php" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="">
    Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
    Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname" value="">
     <input type="submit" name="" value="Update">
     </form>
```

php:

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$sql = "update employee set firstname = '$firstname',
lastname = '$lastname',
where username = '$username'";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    }

    else{
    echo "error: $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

how can I change my code so when the user only wants to change the first name and leave the last name, it wont end up empty in the database?

Comment: You should check if the last name is empty before updating.

Comment: Or in your form you should load the current data before

Comment: check the `$_POST['lastname'] != ' '  || strlen($_POST['lastname']) > $someValue`, if u want it to not be empty or last name with some length, then **if that condition** applies te query is 
`$sql = "update employee set firstname = '$firstname',
where username = '$username'";`
**else**
`$sql = "update employee set firstname = '$firstname',
lastname = '$lastname',
where username = '$username'";`

Answer (score 0):

Add this line your form

```
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>" />
```

`$lastname` is the last name from the resultset. The condition is that you should query the record before rendering the page.

Comment: when I do it like that, the lastname field gets a default value shown in the textfield, which I do not want

Comment: Can you tell me what is stored in your database for this particular field??

Answer (score 0):

Use COALESCE:

```
UPDATE `employee`
     SET `firstname` = COALESCE($firstname, firstname),
     `lastname` = COALESCE($lastname, lastname),
     `username` = COALESCE($username, username)
WHERE `username`= '$username'
```

And leave the value="" out of the HTML form in the input tags.

Comment: but i need the value="", since I am using it in when I call for the form in the php? or a I misunderstanding you?

Answer (score 0):

I recently created a form where I needed to make sure that all fields were filled out, so I used the following code to ensure that all fields were filled out before continuing with my sql query. Probably not the cleanest, but it prevents empty fields. That way nothing will be left blank and it will update accordingly.

```
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];

$flen = strlen($firstName);
$llen = strlen($lastName);

switch ($flen) {
  case 0:
  echo "Click Back button and please make sure to fill in all fields";
  exit;
}
switch ($llen) {
  case 0:
  echo "Click Back button and please make sure to fill in all fields";
  exit;
}
```

Comment: What if fields are not mandatory in this case?? You are trying to force the user to enter all the fields even if it is not mandatory.

Comment: This is just two of the 5 fields I have in my form. In my case, 4 fields are mandatory and one is not, so if they left it blank it would send a NULL. But in my case, I don't have to worry about overwriting existing data because every submission is unique. This is just a quick and simple way to ensure that if data is in the database, it will not be written over by a null value.

Comment: Here the question was about overwriting the existing data in the table. So this could not be an answer.

Comment: The question stated that if they left a field blank it would overwrite the data in the database with a NULL value. All I'm stating here is that by requiring those fields to be filled in, that won't happen. So it's AN answer, though probably not the best. Just what I can offer at this time given my experience.

Comment: Don't think I just underestimated you. See my answer in the post. Instead of doing all the mess, just show what is on the table. If the user wishes to clear, he can update. If not same data is retained.

Comment: In jacub's sql statement, both the firstname and lastname are being updated, in which case requiring both fields to be filled in would ensure that no blank values are written to the database. If they are only changing the first name, they would just type the existing lastname in and it would update correctly.

Comment: Jacub has done a mistake there. As per his question, it seems like he has not rendered the existing data into the form fields. So the user can straight away update without filling in the last name, which will lead to overwriting the existing value. So my point was to show the data in the form and user can do whatever he want to. Hope you got my point.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing i put in the comment, 
U need to check if the person only changed it's **first name**
U could do this

```
include('connection.php');
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
/**
*  instead of checking if the input is an empty string, try to set a minimum
*  length for the string lets put it on 5
*/ 
$minLength= 5;
$sql = '';
if(strlen($lastname) > $minLength && strlen($firstname) > $minLength){
    //both have the  required length
    $sql = "update employee 
            set firstname = '$firstname',
                lastname = '$lastname',
            where username = '$username'";
} else if(strlen($firstname) > $minLength) {
    //only first name with required length
    $sql = "update employee 
            set firstname= '$firstname',
            where username = '$username'";
} else if (strlen($lastname) > $minLength) {
    //only lastname with required length 
    $sql = "update employee 
            set lastname= '$lastname',
            where username = '$username'";
} else {
    //none applied
    $sql = false;
}

if($sql){
//it's "true" if it contains something
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "error: $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

**But i strongly recomment** if u are **updating** information, in the update form by default those field get the current values when the form is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Use prepared statements with `MySQLi`, they are much safer and will help you prevent an **SQL injection attack!**

To solve your problem you can simply check which values came in empty and set a proper query, like this:

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// check if all fields came in and if username is not empty
if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname']))
{
   // you can use strlen($_POST['firstname']) > 2 to check if it at least has 2 characters
   if(!empty($_POST['firstname']) && empty($_POST['lastname']))
   {
       $sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE employee SET firstname = ? WHERE username = ?";
       $sql->bind_param("ss", $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['username']);
   }
   else if(empty($_POST['firstname']) && !empty($_POST['lastname']))
   {
       $sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE employee SET lastname = ? WHERE username = ?";
       $sql->bind_param("ss", $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['username']);
   }
   else if(!empty($_POST['firstname']) && !empty($_POST['lastname']))
   {
       $sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE employee SET firstname = ?, lastname = ? WHERE username = ?";
       $sql->bind_param("sss", $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['username']);
   }

   if ($sql->execute())
   {
      echo "Record updated successfully";
   }
   else
   {
      echo "error: " . mysqli_error($conn);
   }

   $sql->close();
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that if someone leaves the input form fields empty, you want to NOT update that column. 
To do this, build a dynamic query.

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$username = $_POST['username'];
$sql = "UPDATE employee SET ";
//where username = '$username'";
$countColumns = 0; // track how many columns we are going to update
$columns = ['firstname', 'lastname']; // add more columns to this list if needed.
foreach($columns as $key ) {
    if ( ! empty($_POST[$key] ) {
        $value = $_POST[$key];
        if ( $countColumns > 0 ) $sql .= ',';
        $sql .= "  `{$key}` = '{$value}'";
        $countColumns++;
    }
}
if ( $countColumns > 0 ) {
    $sql .= " WHERE username = '{$username}'";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    }

    else {
        echo "error: $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
else {
    // Nothing to update
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work regardless of which they want to update, or if they want to update both. Though I'm not sure if you'd have to escape the single quote inside the strings within the IF statements or not.

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$username = $_POST['username'];

$flen = strlen($firstname);
$llen = strlen($lastname);
$c = $flen + $llen;

if ($flen>0) {
  $fname = "firstname = '$firstname'" ;
}

if ($c=2) {
  $com =  "," ;
}

if ($llen>0) {
  $lname = "lastname = '$lastname'" ;
}

$sql = "update employee set " . $fname . $com . $lname . "
where username = '$username' ";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    }

    else{
    echo "error: $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```